# Pass parameter to java class in PHP

Tags: java, php, xbee

How can I pass parameter to java class in PHP

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('java xbee');  
print_r($output); ?>/*
```

above one is work fine  with my java, now in my scenario, I have to pass the parameter to java class. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access arguments in java within your main method

```
$output = shell_exec('java xbee hello');
```

The hello argument would now be in `args[0]`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

That should print `hello`.